# Combine two tables into one table without using join and without the result creating cartesian product

Tags: mysql

How do I make a table of results of two different ratings without creating a cartesian product. diffrating and hostrating are two different types of user ratings. The users are rating the spots which are are labeled with spotId. userdiffrating and userhostrating are linking the users ratings to the correct spots. I am trying to get all the ratings for a specific spot in a table. Sample data and the expected output are bellow.

Table contents:

userdiffrating:

```
-------------------------------
| RatingId | userId  | spotId |
-------------------------------
| 1        | 1       | 1      |
-------------------------------
| 2        | 2       | 1      |
-------------------------------
| 3        | 1       | 2      |
-------------------------------
```

diffrating:

```
----------------------
| RatingId | userId  |
----------------------
| 1        | 5       |
----------------------
| 2        | 2       | 
----------------------
| 3        | 4       |
----------------------
```

userhostrating:

```
-------------------------------
| RatingId | userId  | spotId |
-------------------------------
| 1        | 1       | 1      |
-------------------------------
| 2        | 2       | 1      |
-------------------------------
| 3        | 1       | 1      |
-------------------------------
```

hostrating:

```
----------------------
| RatingId | userId  |
----------------------
| 1        | 1       |
----------------------
| 2        | 3       | 
----------------------
| 3        | 4       |
----------------------
```

This is what I originally tried but this creates a cartesian product:

```
SELECT D.rating diffrating, H.rating hostrating FROM diffrating D 
JOIN userdiffrating UD ON D.ratingId = UD.ratingId 
JOIN userhostrating UH ON UD.spotId = UH.spotId 
JOIN hostrating H ON UH.ratingId = H.ratingId WHERE UD.spotId = 1
```

Result from first query (cartesian product):

```
-------------------------
| diffrating| hostrating|
-------------------------
| 5         | 1         |
-------------------------
| 5         | 3         | 
-------------------------
| 5         | 4         |
-------------------------
| 2         | 1         |
-------------------------
| 2         | 3         | 
-------------------------
| 2         | 4         |
-------------------------
```

I tried this next query but I cant use a select statement that has more than one row as a subquery:

```
SELECT  D.rating AS diffrating, H.rating AS hostrating

FROM  diffrating D, hostrating H

WHERE D.ratingId = (SELECT ratingId FROM userdiffrating UD WHERE UD.spotId = 1) 

AND H.ratingId = (SELECT ratingId FROM userhostrating UH WHERE UH.spotId = 1)
```

This is the expected result (all diff and host ratings for spotId = 1):

```
-------------------------
| diffrating| hostrating|
-------------------------
| 5         | 1         |
-------------------------
| 2         | 3         | 
-------------------------
| NULL      | 4         |
-------------------------
```

This is the database:
[image: database layout]

Is this possible and how would this be done?
Thanks

Comment: Could you explain a bit functional about this? Like the behaviour of userdiffrating and userhostrating and how they are different from each other. And what you want to achieve functionally?

Comment: Please reaad https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question and add text unstead of images

Comment: And note that an id like '1' will suffice for sample data

Comment: fixed the tables and explained it better

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to code is this

```
SELECT dr.rating diffratingval, hr.rating hostratingval
FROM diffrating dr
JOIN userdiffrating udr
    ON dr.ratingid = udr.ratingid
JOIN userhostrating uhr
    ON udr.spotid = uhr.spotid
JOIN hostrating hr
    ON uhr.ratingid = hr.ratingid
        AND dr.ratingid = hr.ratingid
WHERE udr.spotid = 60;
```

Comment: Only one row is output with this example

Comment: Remove the where condition if you don't need @Dilly

Comment: If I change the where to ```WHERE udr.spotid = 1;``` (to match the example which I edited in the question) Should it not produce 3 rows because in userhostrating there is 3 instances where spotId = 1?

Comment: No, coz your result also requires rating id to be same from diffrating and hostrating too

Comment: Ahh I see. Do you know of any way to get results where the ratingId does not need to be the same? Just the spotId?

Comment: Then you remove this `AND dr.ratingid = hr.ratingid` from last join